# Web usb devices not displaying in chrome windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, webusb

I am using chrome version 86.0.4240.193 in my windows 10 .I am trying to connect usb devices and  cant find any device in `chrome://devicelog`. The same devices are being detected in mac and even in ubuntu 18.04 installed chromes .I am really in a fix any help regarding this ? .Can anyone tell me why this issues occurs
.I have installed and reinstalled chrome many times ,but nothing works.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common reason you will see a device available on other platforms but not on Windows is that Windows imposes additional restrictions on what devices can be controlled from a user-space application such as Chrome. Microsoft provides a special driver called WinUSB.sys which must be the selected driver for the device. If you are building your own device I have published [a guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/build-for-webusb) for designing a device to support WebUSB across all platforms. If you are working with a device you don't have the ability to change then [Zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/) provides a tool for replacing the driver for a USB device with the WinUSB.sys driver.

To see what driver has been selected for your device,

1. Open the Windows Device Manager control panel.
2. Find the device.
3. Right-click on it and select "Properties".
4. Open the "Driver" tab.
5. Click "Driver Details".